# Kotlin Android Compile

Tags: android, compilation, kotlin

I'm getting this error and can't figure out why:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

I think it has to do with android gradle plugin version not being compatible with kotlin gradle plugin version. I didn't upgrade anything, it worked before. But suddenly, this just started to appear and prevent the compilation process.

Is there any public place where i can find the latest android studio plugin based on the latest Kotlin plugin?

thanks in advances,
J

```
StackTrade:

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile.loadChunk(CompressedAppendableFile.java:207)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile.access$700(CompressedAppendableFile.java:36)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile$FileChunkReadCache.get(CompressedAppendableFile.java:482)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile$SegmentedChunkInputStream.read(CompressedAppendableFile.java:522)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMapValueStorage.readBytes(PersistentHashMapValueStorage.java:376)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doGet(PersistentHashMap.java:510)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.get(PersistentHashMap.java:464)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.LazyStorage.get(LazyStorage.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCacheImpl$SourceToClassesMap.get(IncrementalCacheImpl.kt:558)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCacheImpl.classesBySources(IncrementalCacheImpl.kt:128)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:445)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:151)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:117)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at org.iq80.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.readUncompressedLength(SnappyDecompressor.java:410)
        at org.iq80.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.uncompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:38)
        at org.iq80.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.CompressionUtil.readCompressedWithoutOriginalBufferLength(CompressionUtil.java:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile.decompress(CompressedAppendableFile.java:370)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile.loadChunk(CompressedAppendableFile.java:191)
        ... 33 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Please run your build with the --stacktrace option and edit your question to include the stacktrace; this will help understand which problem exactly you've encountered.

Comment: @yole can you please check. I have added the stack trace

Comment: Hi, it seems to that your arraylist is empty, check this line `org.iq80.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.readUncompressedLength(SnappyDecompressor.java:410)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Files > Settings and turn off completely Instant Run, I mean all checkboxes should be unchecked.

Clean and rebuild project.

Also, check your Gradle configuration and update Gradle and Android Studio if you're not using the latest.

According to this issue, changing Gradle plugin version from `2.10` to `2.14.1` may help.

**Protip:** Use combination **Ctrl+Shift+A** to find commands like

- Configure Kotlin in Project
- Configure Kotlin Updates
- Convert Java
  File to Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1.Turn on off Gradle Offline mode it should be online.

2. Clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error recently out of the blue as well. After far too long searching for an answer, I eventually tried Build | Rebuild Project, and it worked. It doesn't seem like a compiler problem, but rather a project setup one (since Kotlin works on my other project).